# Using phantom.js with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, phantomjs

At the moment I am trying to use phantom.js with node.js. I installed the phantomjs in my project directory using the npm package "phantomjs" with "nmp install --save phantomjs". After that wrote the following code in my app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var phantomjs = require("phantomjs");
var path = require("path");
var childProcess = require("child_process");
var binPath = phantomjs.path;

var app = express();

//Set global variables
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views/images");

//Set middleware
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, 'phantomscript.js')
];

childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
});


app.listen(8080);
```

and in the phantomscript.js I wrote a console.log() to test the execution of the file.

When I run the app.js using node nothing happens. I think node.js did not execute the phantomscript.js. Maybe someone knows where my mistake is. Thanks.

ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: where is the `phantomscript.js` i mean are you sure  the path is correct?

Comment: The file is in the same directory as the app.js. The directory is correct. I also didnt get any errors.

Comment: I found the mistake. I forgot to write in phantomscript.js the line 'phantom.exit()'. Now it works.